# Stacking Columns From Right to Left When Screen Resolution Decreases in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, if I have the following:

```
<div class = "row">
     <div class = "col-md-6" id = "one">
     <div class = "col-md-6" id = "two">
</div>
```

and I start decreasing the width of the browser, DIV "two" will eventually form a new row beneath DIV "one".  How would I reverse the stacking order so that DIV "one" gets stacked beneath DIV "two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the new [column ordering classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) from Bootstrap (`.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*`) but you need to make sure the order in which the elements appear in the DOM is the order in which you want them when "stacked":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6" id="two">Two</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6" id="one">One</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/VU8kn/show/)**

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they would affect the stacking order